# How to divide $C_n^k$ combinations into $C_n^k\times k/n$ distinct groups if $n/k$ is an integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Does there always exist a partition like follows?
If $n/k$ is an integer, we can always divide $C_n^k$ combinations into $\frac{C_n^k}{n/k}$ groups such that in each group all of the combinations has no overlapping? No overlapping means any integer appears exactly once in one group. Maybe the word is not accurate, but we can take an example.

For example, let $n=6,k=2$.

Group 1: 12 34 56

Group 2: 13 25 46

Group 3: 14 26 35

Group 4: 15 24 36

Group 5: 16 23 45

Comment: The solution may has something to do with conjugate class or coset in integer group Z_n. I don't know that but maybe someone who is familiar with the relevant field could provide some ideas on it?

Comment: By the way, this problem is about dividing several elements in Galois field to different group in the combination network coding. What I do is just to simplify this problem into a problem 'looks like' a combination problem.

Comment: Nice question! I will think about it.